# How to check if sound played in delphi?

Tags: delphi, audio

I'm using SndPlaySound(pchar('wav.wav'), snd_ASync); function and it is works but I want to know when selected wav is still playing or already played. How to get a return value?

Comment: Play it synchronously by using the `SND_SYNC` flag and wait until the function returns.

Comment: yes but at this case, application will freeze until the end.

Comment: Multimedia subsystem does not provide this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SND_ASYNC` does not provide the information you are looking for.  Use `SND_SYNC` instead.  To avoid blocking your main thread, call `sndPlaySound()` in a worker thread.

Alternatively, have a look at Delphi's `TMediaPlayer` component.  It can run asynchronously (set its `Wait` property to false), and you can use its `OnNotify` event (set its `Notify` property to true) to be told when its `Play()` method finishes playback.

Comment: Thanks, finally I put into a thread and it can be detected if it ends.